# Query to identify which browsers people are using

Tags: mysql

I have a table which stores admin login requests.

```
-- desc AdminLogins

+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(10)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| adminID        | mediumint(9) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| loginTimestamp | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| browser        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The browser field contains the user agent, I want to produce some graphs showing each user agents popularity over the last 6 months but I'm stuck with my query.

so far I have

```
select distinct browser, left(loginTimestamp, 7) from AdminLogins group by left(loginTimestamp, 7);
```

But it isn't returning what I'm after.

Ideally I'd be grouping by the first 7 characters of the timestring, and seeing the distinct user agents for each period.

Comment: There should have some aggregate function since you are using `group by`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select date(loginTimestamp) as logindate,
       group_concat(distinct browser) as useragents
from AdminLogins 
group by logindate
```

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer, and doesn't provide the SQL you need, but does provide information that is going to be necessary for you at some point soon.

User agents are complicated, and may contain lots of detail - you can sometimes identify not just the browser, but the OS, the browser version, and sometimes random crap you'll probably never care about like what version of the .NET framework they have installed.

If you're just dumping the complete user agent string into a MySQL table without doing any kind of processing on it beforehand, you will NOT be able to sanely extract human-meaningful information - much less information that can be reasonably used to form pretty graphs - from that table using SQL alone.

Instead, pull out all the user agents for the time period you're interested in and do your processing using a programming language, instead of SQL. If you're using PHP, you'll want to get an up-to-date `browscap.ini` file and use the [`get_browser`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) function to parse the user agent.

You may want to consider restructuring your existing tracking code to call `get_browser` on user agents when you record them, and record all of the details you care about (e.g. browser, OS, major browser version number, minor browser version number) in separate columns. Then it'll be possible in future to extract useful information using just SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the advice re: get_browser it's something I'll look to implement next time I build anything that requires this sort of logging.